# SQL Server - Refactor Large Union Query

Tags: sql-server, union

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Forms (
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FormName varchar
);

INSERT INTO Forms (ID, FormName)
VALUES (1, 'Password_Reset_Form'), (2, 'Service_Request_Form');

 CREATE TABLE Cases (
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CreatedDt datetime       
 );

 INSERT INTO Cases (ID, CreatedDt)
 VALUES (1, '2018-05-8'), (2, '2018-05-9'), (3, '2018-05-10');

 CREATE TABLE Password_Reset_Form (
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CaseID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cases(ID),
    Subject varchar,
    FormName varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Forms(FormName)
 );

 INSERT INTO Password_Reset_Form (ID, CaseID, Subject, FormName)
 VALUES (1, 1, 'Password Issue', 'Password_Reset_Form');


 CREATE TABLE Service_Request_Form (
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CaseID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cases(ID),
    Subject varchar,
    FormName varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Forms(FormName)
 );  

 INSERT INTO Service_Request_Form (ID, CaseID, Subject, FormName)
 VALUES (1, 2, 'Add User', 'Service_Request_Form'), (1, 3, 'Delete User', 'Service_Request_Form');
```

When each type of form is submitted a new case is recorded in the `Cases` table and all the form data logged in the respective form table e.g. in the above case either the `Password_Reset_Form` table or `Service_Request_Form` table. I have over a 400 these type of form tables and each can contain different fields in addition to the `CaseID`, `Subject` and `FormName` fields.

I want to list all the forms and the number of cases raised for each form between certain dates.

I can do the following but I have to union 100's of tables

```
SELECT t2.FormName, COUNT(1) as TotalCases
FROM Cases t1
INNER JOIN (
   select CaseID, FormName FROM Password_Reset_Form
   union all 
   select CaseID, FormName FROM Service_Request_Form
   /* 400 + more unions */ ) t2
WHERE t1.CreatedDt BETWEEN '2018-05-08' AND '2018-05-10'
GROUP BY t2.FormName
```

Is there a way I can use the `Form` table since that already has a list of form names to simplify the query i.e. use the `FormName` value from this table as table name in my union query or something?

*** Note I cannot change the design as it's propriety database ***

Comment: Probably not. Forms has what forms are available, but not the details of who took it and when. And this is poor design. How did this design not get refactored once it got to like 10 different form tables??

Comment: The problem is your design. You should have a column in a RequestForm table to indicate FormType instead of 100 tables.

Comment: The fact that you can't change the database does not change the fact that the design is the problem. It is awful. I would consider creating a view to return CaseID and FormName from all of these identical tables. Ugh I don't envy you working on this, what a royal PITA!!!

Comment: Write out the code once and do an insert into a custom table a few times a day through a job/ssis package?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the Form table. But you need some other additional structural changes if you want to avoid a large UNION query.

So it depends in how flexible the current database structure is. Are you allowed to change the table structures in your database? If so, I would create a single table for the forms instead of multiple tables. Suppose this table would be called FormCases. It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FormCases (
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FormID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Forms(ID),
    CaseID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cases(ID),
    Subject varchar
);

INSERT INTO FormCases (ID, FormID, CaseID, Subject)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'Password Issue'),
    (1, 2, 2, 'Add User'),
    (1, 2, 3, 'Delete User');
```

Edit: Just saw you cannot change the DB. Then you're out of luck and you do need to use large UNION queries. Sorry.